# Sqoop import Null string

Tags: hadoop, null, hive, teradata, sqoop

The `Null` values are displayed as '\N' when a hive external table is queried.

Below is the sqoop import script:

> sqoop import -libjars /usr/lib/sqoop/lib/tdgssconfig.jar,/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/terajdbc4.jar -Dmapred.job.queue.name=xxxxxx \
>   --connect jdbc:teradata://xxx.xx.xxx.xx/DATABASE=$db,LOGMECH=LDAP --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager \
>   --username $user --password $pwd --query "
>
> select col1,col2,col3 from $db.xxx
>
> where \$CONDITIONS" \
>   --null-string '\N' --null-non-string '\N' \
>   --fields-terminated-by '\t' --num-mappers 6 \
>   --split-by job_number \
>   --delete-target-dir \
>   --target-dir $hdfs_loc

Please advise what change should be done to the script so that nulls are displayed as nulls when the external hive table is queried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sathiyan- Below are my findings after many trials

1. If (null string) property is not included during sqoop import, then NULLs are stored as [**blank** for integer columns] and [**blank** for string columns] in HDFS. 
   2.If the HIVE table on top of HDFS is queried, we would see [**NULL** for integer column] and [**blank** for String columns]
2. If the `(--null-string '\N')` property is included during sqoop import, then NULLs are stored as [**'\N'** for both integer and string columns].
3. If the HIVE table on top of HDFS is queried, we would see [**NULL** for both integer and string columns not **'\N'**]

Comment: To me with `--null-string '\N'` the null-non-string values are written in HDFS as "null", but your guidelines made it work :) They get read correctly as null values.

Comment: To me, not having the ```--null-string``` property leads to values written as 'null', like also stated in the documentation https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html.

Answer (score 6):

In your sqoop script you mentioned `--null-string '\N' --null-non-string '\N` which means,

```
--null-string '\N'  = The string to be written for a null value for string columns 

--null-non-string '\N' = The string to be written for a null value for non-string columns
```

Comment: Yup. That's how the nulls will be stored in HDFS. But, when the hive table is queried, null should be displayed as actual nulls not '\\N'

Comment: No, what ever the string you are giving here will be stored in HDFS, so what ever is stored in HDFS will reflect in hive query.

Answer (score 4):

If any value is NULL in the table and we want to sqoop that table ,then sqoop will import NULL value as string `null` in HDFS. So, that will create problem to use Null condition in our query using hive

For example: – Lets insert  NULL value to mysql table “cities”.

```
mysql> insert into cities values(6,7,NULL);
```

By default, Sqoop will import NULL value as string `null` in HDFS.

Lets sqoop and see what happens:–

```
sqoop import –connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sqoop –username sqoop -P –table cities –hive-import –hive-overwrite –hive-table vikas.cities -m 1
```

http://deltafrog.com/how-to-handle-null-value-during-sqoop-import-export/

Answer (score 0):

In The sqoop import command remove the --null-string and --null-non-string '\N' option.
by default system will assign null for both strings and non string values.

I have tried --null-string '\N' and --null-string '' and other options but getting blank and different issues.